# Configure proxy settings for specific websites not for all HTTP traffic android

Tags: java, android, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

Is there any possibility to configure specific website url to be with proxy settings etc **host** and **port**. I search and found this solution

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "<proxy host>");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "<proxy port>");
```

and also this:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost httpproxy = new HttpHost("<your proxy host>",<your proxy port>);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, httpproxy);
```

but this force all HTTP traffic to pass thru this proxy settings in my case i want if it possible to force only specific sites to be with proxy setup. Don't judge me to much i do my homework first but didn't find any solution in this specific case and if someone know something about this i will be glad.

Comment: Use two separate `DefaultHttpClient` instances: one with the proxy and one without.